# What regular expression do I need to replace the end of the date String to make it uniform?

Tags: regex, swift, nsdate, nsregularexpression

Suppose my input string is one of the following:

```
2015-05-13T09:32:59.771Z
2015-05-13T09:32:59.7713Z
2015-05-13T09:32:59.77133Z
2015-05-13T09:32:59.771999999999Z
2015-05-13T09:32:59.000Z
2015-05-13T09:32:59Z
```

But as an output I always need:

```
2015-05-13T09:32:59.000Z
```

What regular expression do I need?

```
let pattern = ":[0-9]{2}(\.)?([0-9]{0,})?Z&"
```

Comment: You have to replace every line with that string?

Comment: No they are examples, because from the server I may get one of the following results, but I need to always have with `.000Z` at the end

Comment: Just take the first 19 characters and append ".000Z" :)

Comment: I have found a solution for pattern: `"(:[0-9]{2})(\\.[0-9]*)?Z$"` and template: `"$1.000Z"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `(\.[0-9A-z]*)|(([0-9]{2}Z))`

You can also do (if the date and time length is always the same):

```
var sample:NSString = "2015-05-13T09:32:59.771Z"

var substr = sample.substringToIndex(19)

sample = substr + ".000Z"

println(sample) // prints 2015-05-13T09:32:59.000Z
```